# Updating multiple rows by their IDs

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have an ArrayList of IDs and I want to update a certain column in each row corresponding to each ID. What I am trying to do is writing another, existing ID in that column.

I've got a more or less working solution; I'll show it to you first and then describe my problems with it:

```
public static void partnerStmt(ArrayList<Integer> keys, int age, int sex, int variable){
    int amount = keys.size();
    int ageMin = age - variable;
    int ageMax = age + variable;

    if (ageMin < 18)
        ageMin = 18;

    String select = "SELECT ID FROM individuen WHERE Jahre BETWEEN " 
            + ageMin +" AND "+ ageMax + " AND family IS 2 AND married IS NULL AND Sex "
            + "IS " + sex + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " +amount+";";

    try {
        Statement stmt = DBController.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
            int key = keys.get(i);
            int idColumn = rs.findColumn("ID");
            int partnerID = rs.getInt(idColumn);

            PreparedStatement person = DBController.connection
                    .prepareStatement("UPDATE individuen set Partner = " + partnerID +  
                    " WHERE ID = " + key);
            person.executeUpdate();
            rs.next()
            }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My problems with this are, that it is slow. Updating one row at a time just doesn't work with more then 100k entries to be updated. The second problem is, that for some reason IDs, that I am writing into the table (`partnerID`) show up multiple times  after running the programm.

Does anybody know a more efficient and better way of doing something like this?

Comment: Side note: use `PreparedStatements` instead of `Statements` everywhere, and don't concatenate Strings, but use the `setXXX()` methods to set the query parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Use batching functionality of JDBC to reduce the number of round-trips:

```
PreparedStatement person = DBController.connection.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE individuen set Partner = ? WHERE ID = ?"
);
int idColumn = rs.findColumn("ID");
for (Integer key : keys) {
    if (!rs.next()) {
        // Make sure that we do not read a missing parent ID.
        // This should never happen, as long as rs has enough rows.
        break;
    }
    person.setInt(1, rs.getInt(idColumn));
    person.setInt(2, key);
    person.addBatch();
}
person.executeBatch();
```

Note that this code uses parameterized statements with `?` parameters and `setXYZ` methods for supplying values.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I didn't poste the complete post as I say in my comment to Tomer Shemesh. So `partnerID` sadly does change.

Comment: @UsefulUserName The edit happily takes care of that :-)

Comment: Well, thank you again ;) But when I'm using you code I'm getting `java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed` on the line `int idColumn = rs.findColumn("ID");` Does JDBC close resultSets automatically on excecuting batches?

Comment: @UsefulUserName It looks like sqlite's JDBC implementation closes result sets when you make new statements on the same connection. You can rewrite this to get parent IDs in a separate loop, and pair them up with keys as you go. Then walk through pairs, add them to batch, and call `executeBatch()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using in since it looks like your partner id doesnt change

just create a list of your keys and use it like this

```
"UPDATE individuen set Partner = " + partnerID + " WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4)"
```

also even if this doesnt work try moving

```
int idColumn = rs.findColumn("ID");
int partnerID = rs.getInt(idColumn);
```

our of your for loop since it never changes

Comment: In order to use the WHERE ID IN clause make sure that your IDs are split into batches of 999 or 1000 as oracle has an limit of accepting 1000 elements in IN clause

Comment: Sorry, the code I posted was not complete. While deleting some clutter (System.out.println, etc) I accidentily also deleted `rs.next()`. What I'm trying to say is that `partnerID`does change. Or at least it should.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it thanks to you help. I'm still not sure, if this is the most efficient way. So if you've got some suggestions, I'm happy to try them out ;)

```
public static void partnerStmt(ArrayList<Integer> keys, int age, int sex, int range){
    int amount = keys.size();
    int aageMin = alter - range;
    int ageMax = alter + range;
    int[][] storeArr = new int[amount][2];

    if (ageMin < 18)
        ageMin = 18;

    String select = "SELECT ID FROM individuen WHERE Age BETWEEN " 
            + ageMin +" AND "+ ageMax + " AND Family IS 2 AND Partner IS NULL AND Sex "
            + "IS " + sex + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " +amount+";";

    try {
        Statement stmt = DBController.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);

        for (int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++){
            int idColumn = rs.findColumn("ID");
            int idPartner = rs.getInt(idColumn);
            storeArr[i][0] = keys.get(i);
            storeArr[i][1] = idPartner;
            rs.next();
        }

        PreparedStatement person = DBController.connection.prepareStatement(
            "UPDATE individuen set Partner = ? WHERE ID = ?");

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
            person.setInt(1, storeArr[i][0]);
            person.setInt(2, storeArr[i][1]);
            person.addBatch();
        }

        person.executeBatch();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```